# Django 1.4 messages framework

Tags: django, django-views, django-messages

development server use django1.3 but deployment server is powered by django1.4. Messages framework won't work at all on the django1.4 but works great on 1.3 with following code.

settings.py

```
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    )
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        ... ,
    )
```

views.py

```
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    ...

    def some_view(request):
        ...
        mess1 = 'Thank you! Your message was received.' 
        messages.info(request, mess1)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/')
```

template

```
    {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
            {{ message }}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Where is the view that actually renders that template?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the messages template context processor?

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)
```

See this [for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/messages/).